# What ad framework allow user earn reward from installing other apps?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to make an app that reward for user when they installed some recommend app. Like these apps in this link
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/cash-rewarding-mobile-apps
What ad framework can provide this feature? I'm going to make an android app by react native so I prefer a framework that can use with react native.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Applovin had this feature but i am not sure.
you can try or maybe it could be StartApp